# Powershell - DNS Record Removal array question

Tags: arrays, powershell, dns

Im trying to cleanup our DNS Server with some Powershell Code.
There are multiple DNS Records with the **same IP-address**, and I wish to remove all records except the most current for that IP-Address.

I already managed to get the reoccurring IP-Address,Names,Timestamps into an array.
But surely I cannot remove all records except the latest, because the array holds multiple IP-address and I only need to keep the latest record for each ip.

This is what I have so far, any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

```
$CollectionDC = @()
$TotalDuplicateIP = @()

$RecordsDC =  Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName blaa -ZoneName "blaaaa.com" -RRType A

Foreach ($RecordDC in $RecordsDC)
{
$NewObjectdc = New-Object PsObject -Property @{
                    RecordName = $RecordDC.HostName
                    IP = $RecordDC.RecordData.IPv4Address
                    Timestamp = $RecordDC.TimeStamp
                    }    
                $CollectionDC += $NewObjectdc
}
$DuplicateIPDNS = ($CollectionDC.IP | group | ?{$_.Count -gt 1}).Values

foreach($item in $DuplicateIPDNS)
{ 
    if($item.IPAddressToString -like "172.31.*")
    {
        $TotalDuplicateIP  += $CollectionDC | Where-Object {$_.IP -eq $item.IPAddressToString}
    }
}

$TotalDuplicateIP = $TotalDuplicateIP | sort IP,RecordName | Where-Object {$_.RecordName -notmatch "@|DomainDnsZones|ForestDnsZones|gc._msdcs"}

foreach($Record in $TotalDuplicateIP)
{
    $Record

    #Keep only the latest record (timestamp) for each IP

    #Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -WhatIf
}
```

Output Command Above:

```
Timestamp              IP           RecordName    
---------              --           ----------    
12/11/2019 3:00:00 AM  172.31.0.107 blaa-217 #Remove
12/11/2019 11:00:00 AM 172.31.0.107 blaa-247 #Keep
12/10/2019 9:00:00 AM  172.31.0.107 blaa-301 #Remove
12/11/2019 2:00:00 AM  172.31.0.107 blaa-306 #Remove
12/11/2019 7:00:00 AM  172.31.0.107 blaa-320 #Remove
12/11/2019 8:00:00 AM  172.31.0.110 blaa-175 #Remove
12/11/2019 9:00:00 AM  172.31.0.110 blaa-236 #Keep
12/11/2019 8:00:00 AM  172.31.0.110 blaa-318 #Remove
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting the array based on the timestamp and running a for each loop but skipping either the first or last one?

Comment: I thought about it, but it only got me the first or last item of the array in total, instead of the first or last item of each IP (so that only the latest timestamp of that unique ip remains).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change things a little. If you have a lot of DNS records `Group-Object` will take a LONG time to process.

```
$IPRange = '192.168.60.*'
$ZoneName = 'test.local.uk'
$DNSQueryDC = 'mydc.test.local.uk'

# Get DNS records - exclude what you can here as "Group-Object" is slow - it will make subsequent processing faster
$RecordsDC =  Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSQueryDC -ZoneName $ZoneName -RRType A | Where-Object {
    ($_.Timestamp)`
    -and ($_.HostName -notlike "*$ZoneName*")`
    -and ($_.HostName -ne '@')
}

# Get all records matching the IP range
$CollectionDC = $RecordsDC | Where-Object { $_.RecordData.IPv4Address -like $IPRange } | ForEach-Object {
[pscustomobject] @{RecordName = $_.HostName;IP = $_.RecordData.IPv4Address;Timestamp = $_.TimeStamp}    
}

# Group by IP to retrieve duplicates
$CollectionDC | Group-Object -Property IP | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1} | ForEach-Object {
    # Sort by timestamp, then select all except the most recent one
    Write-Host "Found duplicate IPs for: " $_.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $DuplicateIPs = $_.Group | Sort-Object Timestamp -Descending
    Write-Host "`nMost recent record:" 
    $DuplicateIPs | Select-Object -First 1 | Out-Host

    $RecordsToDelete = $DuplicateIPs | Select-Object -Skip 1
    Write-Host "Deleting older records:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $RecordsToDelete | Out-Host
    # Now remove them
    #
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the Group-Object to group an array by similar items.
Once I got that, it all came together.

Below is the completed part.

```
$LatestRecord = @()
foreach($Record in $TotalDuplicateIP | Group-Object IP | Sort-Object Timestamp)
{
    $LatestRecord += $Record.Group | select -Last 1
}

$Filtered = $TotalDuplicateIP | Where-Object { $_ -notin $LatestRecord }

foreach($ToRemoveItem in $Filtered)
{
    #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Removing:" $ToRemoveItem.Timestamp $ToRemoveItem.IP $ToRemoveItem.RecordName
    Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "blaaaa.com" -RRType A -Name $ToRemoveItem.RecordName -RecordData $ToRemoveItem.IP -WhatIf
}
```